# MD5 encryption using jython

Tags: md5, jython, encoder, hashlib

I need to encrypt some data using hashlib encryption in Jython. The output of variable "output" is a set of junk characters "¦?ìîçoÅ"w2?¨?¼?6"

```
m=hashlib.md5()

m.update(unicode(input).encode('utf-8'))

output = m.digest()

grinder.logger.info(digest= " + str(output))
```

How can I get the output as an array for the above code.

Answer (score 0):

`digest()` method return bytes that can be used for other function that require bytes (for example to base64 or compress it). For simply displaying MD5 result as hex use `hexdigest()` method:

```
output = m.digest()
hexoutput = m.hexdigest()
print("digest= " + str(hexoutput))
```